# Cloudant to CouchDB

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-mango

We are developing an application which uses Cloudant as database, which is a variant of Couchdb. Cloudant started to become a bit expensive for us also not reliable because of the last issues. We have lost our connection to DBs for one day. So we decided to build our own Couchdb server.

There are actually two alternatives for us CouchDB 1.6 and 2.0 Developer Preview. Second one provides every feature we need, if we compile it Full Text Search enabled. The first one has no Mango Query, no Dreyfus and Closeau. We can only install couchdb-lucene to enable full text search, but we are actually using Mango, Dreyfus and Closeau intensively in our application.

The problem is that 2.0 is a developer preview version. I am not sure if it is OK to use it on production environment or not. I am searching for alternatives without making too many changes on our application code, for example: is it possible to compile 1.6 with Mango, Dreyfus and Closeau?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible to compile Couchdb 1.6 with Mango, Dreyfus and Closeau  because of changes made in the code base to support them. You're probably better off sticking with cloudant until CouchDB 2.0 is released rather than attempting to run it in production.

Comment: Thanks, since days I have tried many things but this is the conclusion unfortunately. Do you have any idea when 2.0 will be ready for production at least maybe beta release?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just keep an eye on things. Might be work asking on their mailing lists.